# SpringJMS - How to Disconnect a MessageListenerContainer

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I want to disconnect the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` for a queue. I am using `dmlc.stop()`, `dmlc.shutdown()`. At the time of connection 5 consumer threads get connected to queue. When I try to disconnect 4 of the consumers get disconnected, but 1 consumer remains connected.

**Environment**

1. ActiveMQ with AMQP
2. Spring JMS with Apache Qpid

**Problem**
After calling destroy and stop method, there's still one consumer connected to the queue.

**Required Solution**

I want to know, how to cleanly disconnect a `MessageListenerContainer` with zero consumer connections to the queue.

**Configurations and Code**

```java
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer getMessageContainer(ConnectionFactory amqpConnectionFactory, QpidConsumer messageConsumer){
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConcurrency("5-20");
        listenerContainer.setRecoveryInterval(jmsRecInterval);
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(new CachingConnectionFactory(amqpConnectionFactory));
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageConsumer);
        listenerContainer.setDestinationName(destinationName);
        return listenerContainer;
    }

    private void stopListenerIfRunning() {
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) ctx.getBean("messageContainer");
            if (null != dmlc) {
                if(!dmlc.isRunning()){return;}
                dmlc.stop(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        logger.debug("Closed Listener Container for Connection {}", sub.getQueueName());
                        if (sub.getSubscriptionStatus() == SubscriptionStatus.DELETED
                                || sub.getSubscriptionStatus() == SubscriptionStatus.SUSPENDED_DELETE) {
                            listenerHandles.remove(sub.getQueueName());
                        }
                    }
                });
                dmlc.destroy();
                dmlc.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(newCachingConnectionFactory(amqpConnectionFactory));`

You need to destroy the `CachingConnectionFactory`.

You generally don't need a caching factory with the listener container since the sessions are long-lived; you definitely should not if you have variable concurrency; from the javadocs...

```
 * <p><b>Note: Don't use Spring's {@link org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory}
 * in combination with dynamic scaling.</b> Ideally, don't use it with a message
 * listener container at all, since it is generally preferable to let the
 * listener container itself handle appropriate caching within its lifecycle.
 * Also, stopping and restarting a listener container will only work with an
 * independent, locally cached Connection - not with an externally cached one.
```

if you want the connection cached, use a `SingleConnectionFactory` or call `setCacheConsumers(false)` on the CCF.

Comment: I am creating one connection factory and using it in two or more listeners. Is it a bad approach? Shall I use one connection factory per message listener container?

Comment: It's ok, but the CCF caches consumers by default. It's best to use the `SingleConnectionFactory` for listener containers.

Comment: But in this case, you are creating a new CCF `listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(new CachingConnectionFactory(amqpConnectionFactory));`. Which is wrong.